# Hex to decimal conversion in bash without using gawk

Tags: bash, awk

Input:

```
cat test1.out
12 ,         maze|style=0x48570006, column area #=0x7, location=0x80000d
13 ,         maze|style=0x48570005, column area #=0x7, location=0x80aa0d
....
...
..
.
```

Output needed:

```
12 ,         maze|style=0x48570006, column area #=0x7, location=8388621   <<<8388621 is decimal of 0x80000d
....
```

I want to convert just the last column to decimal.
I cannot use gawk as it is not available in our company machines everywhere.
Tried using awk --non-decimal-data but it didnt work also.
Wondering if just **printf** command can work on flipping the last word from hex to decimal.
Any other ideas that you can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the case strtonum() function is not available, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'location=0x' '

function hex2dec(str,
    i, x, c, tab) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            tab[substr("0123456789ABCDEF", i + 1, 1)] = i;
    }
    x = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= length(str); i++) {
            c = toupper(substr(str, i, 1))
            x = x * 16 + tab[c]
    }
    return x
}

{
    print $1 "location=" hex2dec($2)
}
' test1.out
```

where hex2dec() is a homemade substituion of strtonum().

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for awk or any other external commands here: bash's native math operation handle hexadecimal values correctly when in an arithmetic context (this is why `echo $((0xff))` emits `255`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- must be really bash, not /bin/sh

location_re='location=(0x[[:xdigit:]]+)([[:space:]]|$)'

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $location_re ]]; then
    hex=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    dec=$(( $hex ))
    printf '%s\n' "${line/location=$hex/location=$dec}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done
```

You can see this running at https://ideone.com/uN7qNY

Answer (score 1):

Wait, can't you just use `printf` in other awks? It won't work with gawk but it does with other awks, right? For example with mawk:

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}{$NF=sprintf("%d", $NF);print}' file
12 ,         maze|style=0x48570006, column area #=0x7, location=8388621
13 ,         maze|style=0x48570005, column area #=0x7, location=8432141
```

I tested with mawk, awk-20070501, awk-20121220 and Busybox awk.

Discarded after edit but left for comments' sake:

<s>Using `rev` and `cut` to extract around the last `=` and `printf` for hex2dec conversion:</s>

```
$ while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] 
  do 
      printf "%s=%d\n" "$(echo "$line" | rev | cut -d = -f 2- | rev)" \
                        $(echo "$line" | rev | cut -d = -f 1 | rev) 
  done < file
```

Output:

```
12 ,         maze|style=0x48570006, column area #=0x7, location=8388621
13 ,         maze|style=0x48570005, column area #=0x7, location=8432141
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sure is. That's why I usually use awk.

Comment: Ah, it was no gawk but awk is available.

Comment: Removing my legacy comments so you can edit out the content that exists to give them context. Thumbs up on the POSIX-`awk`-based answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Perl installed, not having Gawk is rather inconsequential.

```
perl -pe 's/location=\K0x([0-9a-f]+)/ hex($1) /e' file
```

Comment: perl has a `hex` function, btw.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, I'm apparently too old-skool. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
sed 's/\(.*location=\)\(0x[0-9a-f]\+\)/echo "\1$((\2))"/Ie' file
```

Use pattern matching and back references to split each line and then evaluate an `echo` command.

Alternative:

```
sed 's/\(.*location=\)\(0x[0-9a-f]\+\)/echo "\1$((\2))"/I' file | sh
```

Comment: Piping to `sh` is dangerous. If there were uncontrolled/user-controlled/unknown content in any line in the file, you'd be prone to command substitution vulnerabilities.

Comment: (Consider where your `.*` matches content containing `$(rm -rf ~)` or `"; rm -rf ~; : "` in its text).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. On reflection, perhaps adding a little more validation would be better. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

BASH_REMATCH array info :

http://molk.ch/tips/gnu/bash/rematch.html

quintessential principe :

```
[[ string =~ regexp ]]

[[ "abcdef" =~ (b)(.)(d)e ]]
```

If the 'string' matches 'regexp',

.. the matched part of the string is stored in the BASH_REMATCH array.

```
# Now:
#   BASH_REMATCH[0]=bcde  # as the total match
#   BASH_REMATCH[1]=b     # as the 1'th captured group
#   BASH_REMATCH[2]=c     # as ...
#   BASH_REMATCH[3]=d
```

enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Bash's native math operation handles hexadecimal values correctly anytime.

**Example:**

```sh
echo $(( 0xff))

255


printf '%d' 0xf0

240
```